# Retrieve binary data from Access database using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need a code which retrieve image from access db in vb.net

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection

    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|datadirectory|\img.mdb"

    sql = "select * from picture where ID=" & TextBox2.Text & ""

    Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn)



    'cmd.CommandText = sql

    'cmd.Connection = cn

    'sda.SelectCommand = cmd

    adp.Fill(dt)

    Dim Mydata(0) As Byte

    Mydata = CByte(dt.Rows(0)(1))

    Dim mr As New MemoryStream(Mydata)

    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mr)
```

***Mydata = CByte(dt.Rows(0)(1)) in this line i having issue.....

Comment: The image data is going to be a byte array (`Byte()`) not a single byte.  This  is a assuming it was properly saved.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the line

```vb
Mydata = CByte(dt.Rows(0)(1))
```

triggers the compile-time error

> Value of type 'Byte' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.

If `Option Strict` is `Off` then the `CByte()` conversion is unnecessary. You can simply use

```vb
Mydata = dt.Rows(0)(1)
```

or, even more concisely

```vb
Mydata = dt(0)(1)
```

However, if `Option Strict` is `On` then the above will trigger the compile-time message

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.

In that case you would need to use

```vb
Mydata = CType(dt.Rows(0)(1), Byte())
```

or

```vb
Mydata = CType(dt(0)(1), Byte())
```